# html form send-mail.php get all items in select list not just selected items

Tags: php, html, forms, select, post

In the code below, when I click submit, it will echo the Name and one of items in the select list, if an item is selected. How can I echo all of the items in the select list. None of the items will be selected. The items are just moved into the list to create a list of choices.  Can I get un-selected items?  Or, do I need to write a javascript to select all the items in the left box when the submit button is clicked. If that is what is needed I still don't know how to get multiple items, I think it might be with "implode" but I can't figure out the correct syntax.

========== code below ==========

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$colors = $_POST['colors'];

echo $name;
echo $colors;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Form submission</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
<select name="colors" id="multiSelect" multiple="multiple">
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>

Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

=== below is a sample of the real form without the javascript ===
items are moved from the box on the right side to the box on the right side, when the form is submitted I want to receive a list of the items in the left box

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" width="900px">
    <tr><!-- total the option values added to the select list below-->
        <td valign="top" width="155px"><select id="sourceSelect" size="29" multiple="" style="width:244px";">></select></td>

        <td width="33px">
            <button id="moveAdd" onclick="listboxMoveacross('destSelect', 'sourceSelect', this.id);">&lt;&lt;</button><br>
            <button id="moveSubtract" onclick="listboxMoveacross('sourceSelect', 'destSelect', this.id);">&gt;&gt;</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="destSelect" size="29" multiple="multiple" onchange="showDescription(this);">
                <option value="Blue Box" onclick="showDescription(this);">Temperature Minimum Time</option>
                <option value="Yellow Bird" onclick="showDescription(this);">Temperature Maximum</option>
                <option value="Red Car" onclick="showDescription(this);">Temperature Maximum Time</option>
                <option value="Gree Stick" onclick="showDescription(this);">Wind Speed</option>
            </select>
        </td>

        <td class="test155" width="" valign="top"><div id="putDescriptionHere"> </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdCenter">
            <button onclick="listboxMove('sourceSelect', 'up');">Move Up</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button onclick="listboxMove('sourceSelect', 'down');">Move Down</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td> </td><td> </td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you ever want to echo all options of the select list?

Comment: when no selection is there then why to use select,you can use hidden fields and put these option values to those hidden field values

Comment: The code I posted is a sample just to make it simple. The real code is a long menu of items. When the user clicks an item from the list, the item moves from the "available" items list to a box that displays the chosen items.  When the user clicks the Submit button I want to receive a list of the users chosen items.